# Can I call an API with a MVC pattern program?

Tags: api, http, model-view-controller, backend, httpresponse

I have an API that send a json response, but i want to create a ejs view that handle this response and show the data on my screen. Like a backend that calls another backend. That's possible? And if it's, should i made it?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but I'm pretty sure you can call an API from wherever you want. Why don't you try, and post back when you have a specific question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.